# MySQL update a row but a single field

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

I update a Table with multiple fields. Now one of the fields may only be updated if another field has a defined value, e.g.:

```
 id   | name       | image               | update
--------------------------------------------------
    1 | john       | myimage.jpg         | 0
    2 | ben        | yourimage.gif       | 1
--------------------------------------------------
```

Now i walk through all rows and update all fields but the image should only be update if the "update"-flag is set to 1.
If its 0 the existing value should not be overwritten.

*Now i tried this:*

```
...
`image` = IF(update = 1, VALUES(`image`),`image`)
...
```

but its obviously not working because it overwrites the image in every case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to update the image column Ofer's answer is surely the best. If you'd like to pack the image update into a bigger query, the `IF()` works as follows:

```
IF(expression, return this if expression true, return this if expression false)
```

in your case:

```
UPDATE table t1
SET
t1.image = IF(t1.update = 1, t1.image, 'new image')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
update table
set image = new_value
where update = 1
and id = ?// if you want spacific row, if not ignore this line
```

Answer (score 1):

First just fetch the value of update from  table by query

```
 Select update from your table where id = 'provide row id'


  Then using if else condition by checking value of update fetch fire your update 
   query

 eg.
    if($update == 1)
      {
      echo "Your update query here";
       }

    else
     {
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the name of your column 'update'. It's a reserved word, like you can see below (for updating rows).
I would change it to:

```
ALTER mytable
CHANGE update update_flag tinyint
```

and then use the following for updating your rows:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET image = somevalue
WHERE update_flag = 1
AND id = someid
```

You only need the last line if you don't want to update all your rows where update_flag is 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
update your_table
set `image` = case when update = 1 
                  then $newvalue 
                  else `image`
             end,
    other_column = 'some_value'
```